# Python slice by variable, last index

Tags: python, slice

I have a function that is supposed to return elements from a list in the inclusive slice [a, b].
If a,b are both known, then this is a no-brainer:

```
def my_slice(some_list, a, b):
    return some_list[a:b+1]
```

But, sometimes the user might want the elements in the range [a, final_index] or [0, b] or [0, final_index].
Naively you might just add default values to the parameters

```
def my_slice(some_list, a=0, b=-1):
    return some_list[a:b+1]
```

But this will fail

```
>>> li = range(5)
>>> my_slice(li)
[]
```

Because this is the same as `li[0:0]` which is of course an empty list.

I can do

```
def my_slice(some_list, a=0, b=-1):
    return some_list[a:] if b==-1 else some_list[a:b+1]
```

but I am curious if there is some other way.

Answer (score 2):

You always have to test for parameter b. I would do:

```
def my_slice(some_list, a=0, b=None):

  return some_list[a:b+1] if b else some_list[a:]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
def my_slice(some_list, a=0, b=-1):
    if some_list:
        return some_list[a:b] + [some_list[b]]
    else:
        return some_list
```

I think that should cover all cases:

```
>>> my_slice([1,2,3,4])
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> my_slice([1,2,3,4], 1,2)
[2, 3]
>>> my_slice([1,2,3,4], 1,3)
[2, 3, 4]
>>> my_slice([1,2,3,4], b=1)
[1, 2]
>>> my_slice([1,2,3,4], a=2)
[3, 4]
>>> my_slice([])
[]
```

I'm not sure how you would want to handle slices that extend the list boundaries - ignore them or raise an error?

Comment: Didn't really think of that, to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `None` to include the last position, but you will need to check that you do not have a negative step.

```
i=None
print("abcd"[-2:i])
```

will yield

```
cd
```